# Verifying a Vector Space Via Given Axioms

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $X$ be the collection of all sequences $\{\alpha_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of scalars from $\mathbb{K}$ such that $\alpha_n=0$ for all but a finite number of values of $n$. Define addition and scalar multiplication on $X$ by

$\{\alpha_n\} + \{\beta_n\} = \{\alpha_n + \beta_n \}$ and $\lambda \{\alpha_n\} = \{\lambda \alpha_n\}$.

Verify that $X$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{K}$.

According to my textbook which is being used for this problem, I need to verify the property of closure under addition and scalar multiplication as well as the following 8 axioms:

1). $x+(y+z)=(x+y)+z$

$\{\alpha_n\} + (\{\beta_n + \gamma_n\}) = \{\alpha_n + \beta_n + \gamma_n\}$ and similarly, $\{(\alpha_n + \beta_n)\} + \{\gamma_n\} = \{\alpha_n + \beta_n + \gamma_n\}$ by definition of addition on $X$.

2).$x+y=y+x$

$\{\alpha_n\} + \{\beta_n\} = \{\beta_n\} + \{\alpha_n\}$.

Since $\{\alpha_n\} = 0$ for all but finitely many values of $n$, then $\{\alpha_n\} + \{\beta_n\} = 0+0 = \{\beta_n\} + \{\alpha_n\} = 0+0$.

3). $x+0 = x$.

$\{\alpha_n\} + 0 = \{\alpha_n\}$.

By the definition of addition on $X, \{\alpha_n\} + 0 = \{\alpha_n + 0\} = \{\alpha_n\}$.

4). $x+ (-1)x= 0$.

$\{\alpha_n\} + (-1)\{\alpha_n\}=0$.

Let $\lambda = -1$ and we use the definition of scalar multiplication: 
$\{\alpha_n\}+ \lambda \{\alpha_n\} = \{\alpha_n\} + \{\lambda \alpha_n\}$. Using the definition of addition on $X$, we get $\{\alpha_n+ \lambda \alpha_n\} = \{\alpha_n - \alpha_n\}=0$.

5). $(\lambda + \mu)\{\alpha_n\} = \lambda \{\alpha_n\} + \mu \{\alpha_n\}$.

Using the definition of scalar multiplication on $X$, we can write $(\lambda+\mu)\{\alpha_n\} = \{(\lambda + \mu)\alpha_n\} = \{\lambda \alpha_n + \mu \alpha_n\}$. Using addition on $X$, we can have $\{\lambda \alpha_n + \mu \alpha_n\} = \{\lambda \alpha_n\} + \{\mu \alpha_n\}$. Again using scalar multiplication, we have $\lambda \{\alpha_n\} + \mu \{\alpha_n\}$.

6). $\lambda \{\alpha_n + \beta_n\} = \lambda \{\alpha_n\}+ \lambda\{\beta_n\}$.

By scalar multiplication on $X$,  $\lambda \{\alpha_n + \beta_n\} = \{\lambda(\alpha_n + \beta_n)\}$. Using addition, $\lambda\{\alpha_n+\beta_n\} = \lambda[\{\alpha_n\}+\{\beta_n\}]$. By scalar multiplication, $\lambda[\{\alpha_n\}+\{\beta_n\}] = \{\lambda \alpha_n\} + \{\lambda \beta_n\}$. Again by scalar multiplication, $\lambda\{ \alpha_n\} +\lambda \{ \beta_n\}$.

7). $(\lambda \mu)\{\alpha_n\} = \lambda (\mu \{\alpha_n\})$.

By scalar multiplication, $(\lambda \mu)\{\alpha_n\} = \{(\lambda \mu)\alpha_n\}$. Writing $(\lambda \mu) = (\lambda)(\mu)$, we have $(\lambda)(\mu)\{\alpha_n\}$. By scalar multiplication, $(\lambda)(\mu)\{\alpha_n\} = \lambda\{\mu \alpha_n\}$.

8). $1 \cdot \{\alpha_n\} = \{\alpha_n\}$.

Let $\lambda=1$. By scalar multiplication, $\lambda \{\alpha_n\} = \{\lambda \alpha_n\} = \{1 \cdot \alpha_n\} = \{\alpha_n\}$.

I have not shown the property of closure under addition and scalar multiplication since I am unsure about how to do that with my given information. Any help/advice/suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

The textbook I am using is *Functional Analysis An Elementary Introduction* by Markus Haase.

Comment: What do you mean by closure? that the space is closed w.r.t addition?

Comment: Yes, under addition and scalar multiplication. I have included the edits to my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I think that by "closure" your text-book means that addition and scalar multiplication are well-defined. Indeed, call $V$ your candidate vector space of all the sequences with finite support (i.e., with a finite number of non-zero terms), then you can think to $V$ as a subset of the cartesian product $\mathbb K^{\mathbb N}$ (the space of all sequences indexed by $\mathbb N$ in your field). Of course addition is defined as a function
$$\mathbb K^{\mathbb N}\times \mathbb K^{\mathbb N}\to \mathbb K^{\mathbb N}$$
and similarly scalar multiplication is defined as 
$$\mathbb K^{\mathbb N}\times \mathbb K\to \mathbb K^{\mathbb N}\,.$$
Now, if you restrict the domain respectively from $\mathbb K^{\mathbb N}\times \mathbb K^{\mathbb N}$ to $V\times V$ and from $\mathbb K^{\mathbb N}\times \mathbb K$ to $V\times \mathbb K$, you have to check that the codomain is in $V$. In other words, the sum of two sequences with finite support, as well as a multiple of such a sequence, has again finite support. For this you have just to use the elementary property that $0+0=0$ and $0\cdot\lambda=0$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb K$.

EDIT: Just to be completely explicit, take two elements $\{a_n\}_n\,, \{b_n\}_n$ in $V$ and $\lambda\in \mathbb K$. Then, there exists $m\in\mathbb N$ such that $a_n=b_n=0$ for all $n\geq m$. Of course then $a_n+b_n=0$ and $a_n\lambda=0$ for all $n\geq m$, showing that both $\{a_n+b_n\}_n$ and $\{a_n\}_n\lambda$ belong to $V$.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand your explanation of closure for this space. I believe I actually used those properties in my verification of the axioms without noticing. What about my proofs though? Is there any errors or improvements that can be made?

Comment: Yes, there are possible improvements. Let me list some: (1) In property 1 you are actually using, implicitly, the associativity of addition in your base field, maybe you should make it explicit using parenthesis, (2) the second property does not hold for the reason you wrote, but it holds for the commutativity of addition in your base field. In fact, it is actually false that $\{\alpha_n\}+\{\beta_n\}=0$ for all $\{\alpha_n\}\,,\{\beta_n\}$...

Comment: (3) Your third property is the existence of zero element... from your proof it is not clear who is the zero... of course it is the sequence all of whose elements are zero, it is not clear from what you wrote. your properties 4, 5 and 6 seem OK.

Comment: For property 7: I do not see the utility of writing $(\lambda)(\mu)$, instead of $\lambda\mu$, they mean exactly the same. What you should use here is the associativity of multiplication in the base field, do you see how? Property 8 seems OK.

Comment: How would I go about proving the second part and third part?

Comment: The proof of 2) goes like this:

$\{\alpha_n\} + \{\beta_n\}=\{\alpha_n+\beta_n\}\overset{(*)}{=}\{\beta_n+\alpha_n\} = \{\beta_n\} + \{\alpha_n\}$. Where $(*)$ holds by the commutativity of addition in $\mathbb K$.

Comment: The proof of 3) is the following: we have to show that there exists a neutral element for the sum in our candidate vector space. We affirm that $\{z_n\}$, with $z_n=0$ for all $n$, is our neutral element. We have already seen that addition is commutative so it is enough to verify that $\{\alpha_n\}+\{z_n\}=\{\alpha_n\}$ for all $\{\alpha_n\}$ (otherwise one should also check that $\{z_n\}+\{\alpha_n\}=\{\alpha_n\}$). So, $\{\alpha_n\} + \{z_n\} = \{\alpha_n + z_n\} = \{\alpha_n\}$, since $z_n=0$ is the neutral element for the addition in $\mathbb K$.